# AKMIDICallbackInstrument implementation issue

Tags: swift, xcode, midi, audiokit

Updating to the latest version of AudioKit left me changing several AKCallbackInstrument instances over to the new AKMIDICallbackInstrument class which now incorporates the former as legacy behavior. When doing so however, I ran into this weird error. Maybe a Swift nuance I am missing?

```
let callback = AKMIDICallbackInstrument() { status, note, velocity in
    if status == .noteOn {  //errors out
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comparing **status** to **.noteOn** errors out with:
"Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context.". Makes sense, because AKMIDICallbackInstrument is not returning an AKMIDIStatus in status anymore, but a straight MIDIByte (UInt8). Using direct MIDI command numerics works.

```
let callback = AKMIDICallbackInstrument() { status, note, velocity in
    if status == 0x90 {
       // do something
    }
}
```

So we have a problem and a potential solution. I'm just not sure that this is the way to go and AKMIDICallbackInstrument didn't hit the docs yet.

Comment: Good catch.  The callback instrument should in general be better than what it was before, but there are also more bigger nice changes coming.  I am traveling right now but I can look into this when I am back.

Comment: Hi, any news on that? I am facing this same issue now when upgraded AudioKit to 4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, you can convert the `MIDIByte` to `AKMIDIStatus` like this:

```
let status = AKMIDIStatus(rawValue: Int(statusByte >> 4))
```

On the develop branch, there is a new initializer for `AKMIDIStatus` that directly takes `MIDIByte` as a parameter to make this a little easier.

Comment: Cool - I'll be looking for that new initializer in one of the upcoming releases.